# Parse list to multi-dimensional array without a loop

Tags: ruby, parsing, nokogiri

I'm using Ruby and Nokogiri to parse HTML source and have it list items in a recognizable pattern in the following format:

```
<span class="x">junk</span>
<small class="y">ParameterA</small>
<span class="z">
    <b>ParameterB</b>
    <i>Possible ParameterC</i>
</span>
<script type="text/javascript">useless stuff</script>
<object><noscript>other useless stuff</noscript></object>

<span class="x">junk</span>
<small class="y">ParameterA</small>
<span class="z">
    <b>ParameterB</b>
    <i>Possible ParameterC</i>
</span>
<script type="text/javascript">useless stuff</script>
<object><noscript>other useless stuff</noscript></object>
```

and so on multiple times.

How can I make a multi-dimensional array with the required parameters in the following structure?

```
myarray = []
mystuff = Struct.new(:ParameterA, :ParameterB, :ParameterC)
```

Can't find out what kind of loop I can run here and how can I avoid parsing useless stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this with a regexp which gives me the correct multi-dimensional array as output:

```
[["ParameterA", "ParameterB", "Possible ParameterC"], ["ParameterA", "ParameterB", "Possible ParameterC"]]
```

Working code:

```rb
str = <<EOF
<span class="x">junk</span>
<small class="y">ParameterA</small>
<span class="z">
<b>ParameterB</b>
    <i>Possible ParameterC</i>
</span>
<script type="text/javascript">useless stuff</script>
<object><noscript>other useless stuff</noscript></object>

<span class="x">junk</span>
<small class="y">ParameterA</small>
<span class="z">
    <b>ParameterB</b>
    <i>Possible ParameterC</i>
</span>
<script type="text/javascript">useless stuff</script>
<object><noscript>other useless stuff</noscript></object>
EOF

m = str.scan(/<small [^>]+>([^<]+)<.*?<b>([^<]+)<\/b>\s+<i>([^<]+)<\/i>/m)
puts m.inspect
```

Comment: This works great, i learn nice trick from you. But if ParameterC is not presents in some fields - i have only structs with present C and it skips other values.

Comment: Understand by myself by adding ( )? to required part of regexp, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'ostruct'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<span class="x">junk</span>
<small class="y">ParameterA</small>
<span class="z">
    <b>ParameterB</b>
    <i>Possible ParameterC</i>
</span>
<script type="text/javascript">useless stuff</script>
<object><noscript>other useless stuff</noscript></object>

<span class="x">junk</span>
<small class="y">ParameterA</small>
<span class="z">
    <b>ParameterB</b>
    <i>Possible ParameterC</i>
</span>
<script type="text/javascript">useless stuff</script>
<object><noscript>other useless stuff</noscript></object>
EOT

mystuff = doc.search('small.y').map { |span_y|
  [
    span_y.content,
    span_y.next_element.at('b').content,
    span_y.next_element.at('i') ? span_y.next_element.at('i').content : nil
  ]
}

pp mystuff
```

Which looks like:

```
[
  [
    "ParameterA",
    "ParameterB",
    "Possible ParameterC"
  ],
  [
    "ParameterA",
    "ParameterB",
    "Possible ParameterC"
  ]
]
```